# Cannot test the admob API throws Ad failed error

Tags: android, admob

When I try to test the Admob api I get the following error in my logcat.

```
 Ad failed: com.google.ads.AdView{40db6b18 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-480,610 #7f070001 app:id/adView}Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.
```

Answer (score 0):

Admob can return a blank ad (depends on targeting, user preferences etc), there is a fill rate in admob less then 100%, my suggestion to you - create some "house ads" that will return when you ads are blank.

*Or simply add some test ads, as i remember you can find such a feature in admob.

Comment: I'm using the testing feature.

Comment: Dinesh, it sounds like you are not correctly using the test ads. You do not get this message with test ads.

Comment: I'm using the mediation Id to get ads.

Comment: post your code to get adds. Do you enable internet etc in your manifest ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Logcat showing (no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory). It Clearly means that admob is not serving any advertisement to your app at that time.

It is probably because of the fill rate.
You can use AdSense to help backfill ads when AdMod does not have any available.

Comment: Check this link http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1307260. Try to accept my answer if its useful for you. thanks.